# Hyperledger Fabric - Configtxlator - Decode blockchain data

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I'm trying to decode blockchain data stored in a HyperLedger v1.4.1 peer.

I found the `blockfile_000000` file in `/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/chains/mychannel`

and I'm using the `configtxlator` to decode it.

But when I run the following command:

```
./configtxlator proto_decode --input blockfile_000000 --type common.Block
```

I get this error:

```
configtxlator: error: Error decoding: error unmarshaling: proto: can't skip unknown wire type 4
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is your goal to decode the entire ledger or do you just want to be able to decode individual blocks?
`configtxlator` will not be able to decode the block file (which contains many blocks); you'll need to fetch individual blocks and decode each one.

Comment: @Gari Singh thanks for your answer. I'm trying to do that to better understand how data are stored. Where I can find single blocks in the peer filesystem?
I have also another question, are the blocks encrypted in the filesystem or are they readable to anyone who have access to the peer?